# Create Display Template without a master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to create a new site template without including master page. Is there any way to implement this.?

Comment: Design Template or Display Template? Please correct title/body of your question.

Comment: Do I able to use reusable content to create a page template instead of a master page

Answer (score 0):

make a new minimal master page and hide all the elements you dont want, and use that as your master?

Comment: I need to use template instead of master page

Comment: I need to create custom site .stp file